# Issues align horizontally text in the menu on responsive svg footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I can't align horizontally these informations that are not links but informations... I would like to align it with pourcentage from the right bottom corner

All the examples I founded on the Internet are with the links examples but it seems like I'm missing something, and I'm very new to html css... sorry if I ask dumb question...

```css
footer {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0;
  height: 77px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  font: 30px "Elastik-B";
  z-index:99;

}

.footer ul{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type: none;   
}


.footer li {
   position:absolute;
   margin: 20%;
   padding:5px;
   display: inline-block;
   bottom:15px;
   right:5%;
```

```html
<footer>
<div class="footer">


<ul>
    <li><div id="humidity">15%</div></li>
    <li><div id="temp">15°</div></li>
    <li><div id="clock">15h15m15s</div></li>
    <li><div id="date" class="date">15.15.15</div></li>
  </ul>




    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 1670 97" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<g>
    <path fill="#FE4A11" d="M1669,52.659V97H847.357H0V52.659l122.675-16.814l142.712,3.871c0,0,231.45-27.464,236.787-27.78
        c5.336-0.316,272.148,27.132,272.148,27.132l198.221-14.81l360.398,14.679l231.414-15.818L1669,52.659z"/>
    <path fill="#FE4A11" d="M1669,52.659V97H847.357H0V52.659l122.675-16.814l142.712,3.871c0,0,231.45-27.464,236.787-27.78
        c5.336-0.316,272.148,27.132,272.148,27.132l198.221-14.81l360.398,14.679l231.414-15.818L1669,52.659z"/>
</g>
</svg>

</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: `position:absolute;` should be on the `ul` not the `li`

Comment: https://codepen.io/molonom/pen/yWqxWp

Now it seems like there is another problem... There is no horizontal block anymore...